# issue sending and retrieving value using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a cleaner code of my preview problem, the idea is to send and retrieve a value using ajax, but the value is not being sent nor ajax seems to work. I updated this code because this way it could be easily tested on any machine. First time using ajax. Here is the code:

Javascript

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#centro').click( function() {
$.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
        alert(output_string);
                $('#cuentas').html(output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call    

  });
 }
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <?php
  $result = 'works';
  ?>

  <form id="form">
  <div id="centro">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="centro" value="<?php echo $result; ?>">
  </form>

  <div id="cuentas">
  </div>
```

PHP file, request.php

```
 <?php
 $centro = $_POST['centro'];
 $output_string = ''.$centro;
 echo json_encode($output_string);
 ?>
```

Comment: What's `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: On top of your `load_cuentas.php`, put `var_dump($_POST);` and see what values is it getting in the first place? and please share the output with us

Comment: @HerlandCid He means add `var_dump($post)` and add the results of it to your question. It will of course make your ajax request fail though due to the response no longer being valid json.

Comment: I put $output_string = ''.var_dump($_POST); and I get nothing. not sure if i'm applying the var_dump($_POST); I assumed it as a function retrieving something

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you never tell AJAX that the POST name is 'centro', try to change this:

```
data: $("#form_"+i).serialize(),
```

for this

```
data: { 'centro' : $("#form_"+i).serialize()},
```

Comment: It's a hidden input in the form in his first snippet.

Comment: thanks @KirKill I updated, but it still throws null in the alert

Comment: Try to see if $_POST['centro'] is really the problem, echo it and exit after, you should see it's value in your alert.

Comment: If you want to debug AJAX calls, I recommend you use Google Chrome console, when you do AJAX calls you will see them in the Network tab in the console, so you will see the actual PHP page when you click on the call and if the error is php-side you will be able to see it.

Comment: You say that the $_POST['centro'] is always empty, so maybe the problem is with your jquery selector? Try to replace $("#form_"+i).serialize() with $('input[name="centro"]').serialize()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    $f=0;
    $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM centro");
    if($db->num_rows($consulta)>0){
        while ($resultados1 = $db->fetch_array($consulta)){   ?>
        <form id="form_<?php echo $f++; ?>"> //begin form with its id
            <div class="centro" id="centro_<?php echo $i++; ?>">
                <a href="#"> <?php echo $resultados1['nombre_centro']; ?></a>
                <br>
                <input type="hidden" name="centro" value="<?php echo $resultados1['id_centro']; ?>">
                <!--this is the data that is going to be sent. I set up a hidden input to do it.-->
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="cuentas" class="cuentas">
            <!--where data is  going to be displayed-->
        </div>
        <br>
        <?php  
        }
    } 
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.centro').on('click',function() {
        var formElem=jQuery(this).closest('form');
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: 'load_cuentas.php',
            cache: true ,
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(formElem).serialize(),
            success: function(output_string){
                jQuery(formElem).next('div.cuentas').html(output_string);
                alert(output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call 
    });
});

</script>
```

**Server page:**

```
<?php
    include ('mysql.php');
    $db = new mysql();
    $centro = $_POST['centro']; //this is not getting any data. the whole ajax thing
    $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE id_center = '$centro'");
    $output_string=array();
    if($db->num_rows($consulta)>0){
        while ($resultados1 = $db->fetch_array($consulta)){   
            $output_string []= 'test text';
        }
    }               
    mysql_close();
    echo json_encode($output_string);
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Rohan, this time it throws a '[]' the problem is with the $_POST['centro']; don't know why it isn't being sent

Comment: Check what you got in `$_POST['centro']`, also check your query that it returns not null. You can add two lines:
`$output_string ['sql']= "SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE id_center = '$centro'";`
before `echo json_encode(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem with my ajax calls that I call via the `POST` method. My data was actually getting passed in the message body. I had to access it through the following method:

```
php://input
```

This is a read only wrapper stream that allows you to read raw data from the message body.

For more information on this wrapper visit [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Tray adding the following to your PHP file:

```
$centro = file_get_contents("php://input");
// Depending on how you pass the data you may also need to json_decode($centro)
echo json_encode($centro); 
// See if you get back what you pass in
```

This read the message body (with my posted data) and I was able to access the value there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @War10ck for your answer :) it gives a result, the result this time is as blank

Comment: @HerlandCid No problem buddy. What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: Well, in the php file, if the it gets the variable, and runs the query, the result should be 'test text' @War10ck

Comment: @HerlandCid So the query returns a blank or the echo returns a blank? Sorry I'm just a little confused. Before you call the query, is the value making it to the php code? If you are getting your value back, that's step 1. If you still are not getting a value (before you call your query) then we need to dig a little deeper into your code.

Comment: the echo using the variable is blank @War10ck. I am trying to echo $_POST['centro']; and that is blank

Comment: @HerlandCid I never could get my information to pass in the `$_POST` stream. Even though I was doing a `POST` in the ajax call. Replace `echo $_POST['centro'];` with the two statements I have in my answer. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hey @War10ck I updated my code to a far cleaner and readable one, which can be tested without any issue on any machine. This time ajax is not working don't know why. It worked like charm before.

Answer (score 0):

try to using this code in your ajax post :

```
jQuery('#centro_'+i).click( function() {
$.ajax({

    data: $("#centro_"+i).closest("form").serialize(), 
    dataType:"html", 
    success:function (data, textStatus) {
                $('#cuentas').html(data);
                alert(data);}, 
    type:"post", 
    url:"load_cuentas.php"

        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, the ajax with the post works now. but the alert is still showing as blank.

Comment: try to echo as html : echo $output_string;

Comment: thanks @AhmedAtta I did $centro = ` $_POST['centro']; echo $centro; ` and still shows blank.

Comment: when using in ajax post dataType:"json"  you must using in file load_cuentas.php json_encode() function.